# how to use for loop with JSX elements to print content of collection into multiple <Text> tags in React Native?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, react-native, jsx

Basically I want to achieve the topology below within React Native render():

```
<View>
   <Text>collection.key1</Text>
   <Text>collection.key2</Text>
   <Text>collection.key3</Text>
               .
               .
               .
   <Text>collection.keyN</Text>
</View>
```

But I struggle with using for loop with JSX tags since I'm very new to JSX.
Here's my code that's not working to give you more idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
collectionToView(collection, keys)
{
  let rows = [];
  for (key in keys)
  {
      rows.push(<Text> key + ": " + collection[key] </Text>);
  }
  return rows;
}
```

and later inside a `scrollView` I would like to render it like to render it like this somehow:

```
<View>
   {this.collectionToView(userData, {'serial','product_id','product_name','status'})}
</View>
```

Can anyone show me how to achieve this in React Native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
renderItem() {
  const list = [
    {
      price: '5,000',
      text: 'April stay also',
    },
    {
      price: '6,000',
      text: 'May stay also',
    },
  ]

  return (
    <View>
      {list.map((val, key) => 
        <View key={key} >
          <Text>{val.price}</Text>
          <Text>{val.text}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

use:

```
<View>
  {this.renderItem()}
</View>
```